# Android change ProgressDialog drawable while dialog works

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a ProgressDialog which i started when Activity is Created(insideOnCreate method).

```
private void initDialog() {
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait.");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to LinkedIn.");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();
}
```

**After 2500ms** i want to change a circle animation to my custom image(see below) (like an a simulation about when i finish retrieve some data from server and i'm done.) So i need to show user that process is finished. For this goal i select a next way.

1. I show dialog
2. When i retrieve data i change drawable of ProgressDialog

And this i have a problem. When i set the first time a drawable

```
private void initDialog() {
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait.");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to LinkedIn.");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    //This
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ok));
    mProgressDialog.show();
}
```

ProgressDialog change drawable and all looks ok. But when ProgressBar launched(worked/circle animation playing) i try to reset a drawable

```
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ok));
```

And i have unexpected result : circle animation disappear and no image set to current progress drawable. NO IMAGE! BLANK AREA instead of my image.

```
    authButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ok)); //doesn't work as expected!
        }
    }, 2500);
```

#### So my question is - how i can change drawable in runtime during ProgressDialog works?

### [image] need to be changed to [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Finally i find a solution

`ProgressDialog` contains inside a `ProgressBar` which display our drawable.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(a.getResourceId(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog_horizontalProgressLayout, R.layout.alert_dialog_progress), null);
mProgress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress); // THIS
mProgressNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_number);
mProgressPercent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_percent);
setView(view);
```

When we try to set drawable again to `ProgressDialog`,ProgressDialog **really set a new drawable**. **But this drawable didn't have a bounds** (coordinates to display this view). 
So we must set it hardly. I choose a copy way - just a copy bounds from current drawable of `ProgressDialog`. You can use another way.

#### Initialize dialog :

```
private void initDialog() {
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait.");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to LinkedIn.");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
}
```

#### Show

```
    mProgressDialog.show();
```

#### Change drawable

```
private void changeToDone(int resId) {
    //Getting a progressBar from dialog
    ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) mProgressDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
    //Getting a DONE(new) drawable from resources
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resId);
    //Getting a drawable from progress dialog
    Drawable indeterminateDrawable = bar.getIndeterminateDrawable();
    //Obtain a bounds of current drawable
    Rect bounds = indeterminateDrawable.getBounds();
    //Set bounds to DONE(new) drawable
    drawable.setBounds(bounds);
    //Set a new drawable
    bar.setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable);

    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Done.");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Connected.");
}
```

### Note :

*Solution untested on specific cases like an*

- We have a progress bar in `ActionBar`/`TitleBar`
- Another cases when we already have an `android.R.progress` on the screen window. In this case i think my solution will be produce unexpected behavior.

Comment: bar.getIndeterminateDrawable method doesn't exist in ProgressBar class though in 2020 android studio 3.7. I just had to set an arbitrary bounds. But ProgressBar is so good - Google shouldn't deprecate it. In iOS had to use a library but, ProgressBar is good in Android.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void initDialog(boolean is) {
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait.");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to LinkedIn.");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    if(is) // take global variable
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    mProgressDialog.show();
    if(!is)
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mProgressDialog.cancel();
            mProgressDialog = null;
            initDialog(true);   
        }
    }, 2500);
```

For first time call with `initDialog(false);`

As far as I checked indeterminate drawable cannot really be replaced, so this workaround can save you from creating custom ProgressBar.

Comment: Yes. It works, But it's blinked because we show a new **instance** of `ProgressDialog`

Comment: yes, I faced same situation had two options either use this one or create a custom ProgressBar.